# javascript object function

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to get the function feedAmount to print to the console but am getting stuck. Can someone help straighten me out (and optimize this if it needs to be)? As an added question, could I prototype? chicken.prototype.chickenFeed("small")? Thanks!

```
var chicken = new chickenObj("cluck");
chicken.talk();

function chickenObj(says) {

    this.says = says;

    this.talk = function talk() {
        console.log("::" + this.says);
    }
}

chicken.chickenFeed = new chickenFeed("small");
chicken.chickenFeed.foodAmount();

function chickenFeed(size) {

    this.size = size;

    function foodAmount() {

        if(this.size === "small") {
            this.food = "1 pound of feed";
        } else if(this.size === "medium") {
            this.food = "2 pound of feed";
        } else if(this.size === "large") {
            this.food = "3 pound of feed";
        }

        console.log(this.food);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever downgraded a question could have at least left an explanation of why they downgraded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function chickenFeed(size) { 
    this.size = size;
}

chickenFeed.prototype.foodAmount = function () { 

    if (this.size === "small") { 
        this.food = "1 pound of feed";
    }
    else if (this.size === "medium") { 
        this.food = "2 pound of feed";
    }
    else if (this.size === "large") { 
        this.food = "3 pound of feed";
    }

    console.log(this.food);
};
```

And while you are at it put the `.talk` to `chickenObj.prototype` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want foodAmount to be available you need to either define it on the object that gets created by the constructor (with this.foodAmount) or on the function prototype (chickenFeed.prototype.foodAmount)

```
function chickenFeed(size) { 
    this.size = size;

    this.foodAmount = function() { 
        if (this.size === "small") { 
            this.food = "1 pound of feed";
        } else if (this.size === "medium") { 
            this.food = "2 pound of feed";
        } else if (this.size === "large") { 
            this.food = "3 pound of feed";
        }

        console.log(this.food);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
function chickenFeed(size) { 
    this.size = size;
}

chickenFeed.prototype.foodAmount = function() {
    if (this.size === "small") { 
        this.food = "1 pound of feed";
    } else if (this.size === "medium") { 
        this.food = "2 pound of feed";
    } else if (this.size === "large") { 
        this.food = "3 pound of feed";
    }

    console.log(this.food);
}
```